# SIM tool error installing new sitecore instance

Tags: sim

I want to install sitecore 8.2 instance through SIM tool but it's throwing below error

[image]

I copied exe file in repository folder but it's not working. I tried to copy sitecore 8.2 zip file in repository folder but encountered same error. I cleaned up my temp folder as well but same result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SIM only works with `ZIP archive of the Sitecore root folder` archives, not with the `.EXE` installer versions.

[image]

Also, it relies on the archive name being exactly the same as it is when downloaded directly from Sitecore. So if the 8.2 zip you have has been renamed or altered in any way, SIM will not recognise it.